# CORS : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present Angular 2

Tags: http, angular, cors

I'm trying to implement a service that make a PATCH Http call, it's the only methode where i get this error " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present " and when i check the developper Tool on chrome i see an OPTION instead of PATCH, here is my methode :

```
pauseTasksJobs(id, task){

//this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'application/json');
//this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

  var url = this.home+ "tasks/" +task+ "/jobs/" + id ;
  var body = "{  \" status \"  : \"Pause\" }";
  //var body = "{ status : Pause }";
   console.log("this is my body: "+body) 

   var result;

    this._http.patch(url,body,this.requestOption).
    map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
               result = res;
              console.log("this is my result: "+result);
    },  error=> console.error('Error: ' + error),()=>console.log("tasks mis en pause"));
}
```

And in my constructor i'm setting the header content like this :

```
headers = new Headers();
 requestOption = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

  private actionV: string;

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + cookieValue);
  }
```

Comment: which backend do you use

Comment: if you mean which server:  i'm using TOMCAT

Comment: In your tomcat configuration, search for the value of the parameter: cors.allowed.methods. It will list the allowed methods, is PATCH among them?

Comment: yeap it is among them

Comment: the problem is with your cors preflight. It will first send a OPTIONS request and if that succeeds it will send the PATCH request. So OPTIONS also needs to be in cors.allowed.methods. If that does not work, try sending in the headers (which are now commented out). Can you provide some more code on how the headers are appended to this.requestOption?

Comment: and options is cors Allowed on tomcat :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "and options is cors Allowed on tomcat". Tomcat needs to respond with the proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for options requests. `application/json` is not the correct value for that header.  It should be either `*` or the url of the origin.

Comment: I mean in the cors.allowed.methods on tomcat : there is PATCH and OPTIONS there, and like stijn26 mentionned i think my problem is on the preflight, i've tried changing the value of the header to ' * ', still no improvement

Comment: Your changes don't seem to take effect. If the browser complains that there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header then this is because the response to the `OPTIONS` request it made didn't contain this header.

Comment: yeah the response does not contain the access control origin, please see these screenshots : [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ibGP6.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BlDeM.png

Comment: Try this: this._http.patch(url,body, {headers: this.headers})

Comment: @stijn26 still the same problem :(

Comment: Then try to put Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * somewhere in the tomcat config, I don't have experience with Tomcat so can't help you there. Also delete this line from @Daredzik's answer: headers.append('Content-Type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers');

Answer (score 0):

First at all, add header to your patch request in angular.

like this:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers');
```

And don't forget add header to your http request, like this:

```
this.http
    .patch(url, JSON.stringify(payload), { headers: headers })
    ...
```

Secondly in your tomcat config, you need configure:

```
 <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
 <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
    <param-value>Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Last-Modified</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Angular on PATCH first sending OPTIONS, then why we need allow OPTIONS in CORS.

Hope it helps ?

Comment: that's pretty much what i've tried, it did not solve the issue, thx for your answers

Comment: @Anna ok, for sure u tried witch `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'` ;)

Comment: yeah, still not getting the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the response header

Comment: @Anna then its not problem of angular, but of tomcat. Can you try on other server ?